# T-SQL constraint to check if value is either 0 OR unique

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, constraints, ddl

I'm designing a DB where employees need to be activated by an Admin. When a new employee registers, their workstation (int) gets set to 0 by default. However, I also can't allow to have more than 1 employee per workstation. So I was thinking if there's a way to allow for duplicates of the value 0, but enforce that any other number be unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a partial unique index. For example:

```
create unique index ix1 on employees (workstation) where workstation <> 0;
```

As in:

```
create table employees (
  id int, 
  name varchar(10), 
  workstation int not null
);

create unique index ix1 on employees (workstation) where workstation <> 0;

insert into employees (id, name, workstation) values (1, 'Anne', 100);

insert into employees (id, name, workstation) values (2, 'Peter', 101);

insert into employees (id, name, workstation) values (3, 'Joel', 100); -- fails

insert into employees (id, name, workstation) values (4, 'Niko', 0);

insert into employees (id, name, workstation) values (5, 'Akina', 0); -- succeeds
```

This is one of the constraints that you cannot enforce using traditional constraints.

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a35a2adb4be4b81af6bb8b8695bdd5d0). As you see only `Joel, 100` is rejected. The other two cases with `workstation` = 0 are inserted.

Comment: Yes, this is called a _filtered index_ and is made necessary because this is one of the rare scenarios where SQL Server bucks the standard and treats two separate NULLs as equal.

Comment: @AaronBertrand . . . I wouldn't say "one of the rare scenarios":  `+` instead of `||`, no support for `null`-safe comparisons, no full support of `range` window frames, using `=` as an assignment operator for column aliases, lack of support for `extract()` and a bunch of other "standard" functions, requirement of `offset` with `fetch` . . . I could go on.  My point is not to actually pick on SQL Server, but I wouldn't call `NULL` treatment a rare example.  ;)

Comment: @Gordon I meant rare scenario where it handles NULLs in a non-standard way, not rare scenario where it bucks the standard. A lot of the proprietary stuff can be beneficial, and no RDBMS is 100% compliant. If they were all compliant and only compliant they would all be the same. :-)